# Getting incorrect encoding when reading JSON Sinatra

Tags: android, json, ruby, retrofit

Using Sinatra I've created a web server and now I'm trying to pass some data there. I'm passing it using Retrofit (android) and Gson as a converter.

Here is a logcat log:

```
 --> POST http://192.168.88.147:4567/payload HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 245
[{"composition":"","name":"Чебурек с мясом","price":42,"type":"выпечка","weight":"100","mId":158},{"composition":"","name":"Ватрушка с картошкой","price":32,"type":"выпечка","weight":"100","mId":159}]
 --> END POST (245-byte body)
 <-- 200 OK http://192.168.88.147:4567/payload (164ms)
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: 448
 X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
 X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Connection: keep-alive
 D/OkHttp: Server: thin
 D/OkHttp: OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1472197883936
 OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1472197884075
 [{"composition"=>"", "name"=>"\u0427\u0435\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0435\u043A \u0441 \u043C\u044F\u0441\u043E\u043C", "price"=>42, "type"=>"\u0432\u044B\u043F\u0435\u0447\u043A\u0430", "weight"=>"100", "mId"=>158}, {"composition"=>"", "name"=>"\u0412\u0430\u0442\u0440\u0443\u0448\u043A\u0430 \u0441 \u043A\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043E\u0448\u043A\u043E\u0439", "price"=>32, "type"=>"\u0432\u044B\u043F\u0435\u0447\u043A\u0430", "weight"=>"100", "mId"=>159}]
<-- END HTTP (448-byte body)
```

Pay attention that this is cyrillic.

Here is the Ruby serverside code how I'm doing this:

```
post '/payload' do
  push = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
  push.inspect.force_encoding("UTF-8")
end
```

I used some third party online decoder and it said that this unreadable text is UTF16.

Please help me to find out what is going on here. 
I'm new in Ruby.

Also consider to rename this question, because maybe I'm misuse some terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Windows 7** was the problem. As soon as I switched to Ubuntu(virtual box) I got the encoding correctly withoud any encode\decode manipulations.